# Remove fractional part from CSV file in specific column?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have the CSV file like below

```
MK0280,GCA_000007185.1,AAM01497.1,430,1 430,430,COG0001,COG0001,0,570.0,1.0e-200,432,3-431 
MA_0581,GCA_000007345.1,AAM04025.1,424,1 424,424,COG0001,COG0001,0,574.0,1.0e-200,432,3-426
```

I want the output like below

```
MK0280,GCA_000007185.1,AAM01497,430,1 430,430,COG0001,COG0001,0,570.0,1.0e-200,432,3-431 
MA_0581,GCA_000007345.1,AAM04025,424,1 424,424,COG0001,COG0001,0,574.0,1.0e-200,432,3-426
```

Want to remove decimal part from column 3. Any sed/awk or other suggestion?

Comment: Try `awk '{gsub(/\.?/,$3)}1' file`

Comment: In case some are wondering, the "1" after the braces is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643240/what-does-a-number-do-after-curly-braces

Comment: The code posted by shishi above removes all the `.` characters when I run it, which I don't think it what the OP asked?  This worked for me  `gawk -F, -vOFS=, 'sub("\\..*","",$3)' file`

Comment: I would even be more specific with the regex by using `'sub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", $3)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that should do it. Since we are working with CSV, best way is to use FPAT field separator with a possibility of embedded commas within the data elements; in which case those data elements should be surrounded by a pair of double quotes.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' -v OFS=, '{
    split($3,temp,"[.]")
    $3=temp[1]
    print}' sample.csv
```